# Cross domain request to web-service returning JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to doing a request to a web service from an ASPX page on www.mysite.com using jQuery.

My webservice is hosted on https://www.mysite2.com.

I've tried to perform the request in this way (I found part of this code online):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.mysite2.com/ws/api/Visits/List/" + myfilter,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: setHeader,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.visits, function (v, i) {
            return {
                label: v.ID,
                value: v.Name
            }
        }))
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error!');
    },
})

function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Token', 'myToken0123');
}
```

I encounter two problems:

1) IE is returning Access Denied error (code 0x80070005)

2) Chrome is returning "Insecure response" error

The returned JSON will be used to fill an autocomplete source.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` on a GET request? There's no content in a GET request to describe the type of!

Comment: Yes, you're right. Forgot to delete before posting. Sorry.

Comment: It's probably because you're trying to get from a self-signed SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Cross Domain Request then you need to contact whom ever is in charge of the server and ask them to add your domain to their list. This is the code they would need to add to the server where http://foo.example is your domain.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

Comment: The web service server is mine, so I can try to add this code without problems.

Comment: If the domain is yours and the application is hosted on that domain then why are you doing a crossDomain: true, in the ajax call?

Comment: I've add these lines to web.config but it is still not working. I've also tried with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` wildcard value (*) without success. My situation is: webService SRV: wssite.com, WebApp SRV: webapp.com. They are in different servers and domains.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://www.mysite2.com, it will tell you This server could not prove that it is www.mysite2.com; its security certificate is from *.hawkhost.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker.

You can accept this and you will no longer see your issue. However, every single one of your users would have to do the same.